# Using TORUS how i can sign a raw transaction?

Tags: wallets, signature, quorum

I am using TORUS wallet to make transactions over Quorum network. The requirement is to make a private transaction, for which we need to sign a raw transaction. TORUS does not allow to sign a transaction for security purposes. Is there any way to sign a raw transaction with TORUS wallet?